# Dynamic field name in Access query and function, can this be done?

Tags: function, ms-access, dynamic, concatenation, field-names

in an access database i have created a function which compares 3 fields in my query:

Fields:  
CostMacDON   
CostKentFRY   
CostBurgKIN   
TurnMacDON   
TurnKentFRY   
TurnBurgKIN   
CustMacDON   
CustKentFRY   
CustBurgKIN

```
Public function Eval(MacD, KentF, BurgK)
'Note: the real evaluation is a bit more complex, this is just an oversymplified example
if MacD>KentF and MacD>BurgK
 Eval="MD is the highest"
else
 Eval="MD is NOT the Highest"
endif
```

end function

to call the function in a access query view i use

```
Evaluate Cost: Eval(CostMacDON, CostKentFRY, CostBurgKIN)
         ====       ----        ----         ----
Evaluate Turn: Eval(TurnMacDON, TurnKentFRY, TurnBurgKIN)
         ====       ----        ----         ----
Evaluate Cust: Eval(CustMacDON, CustKentFRY, CustBurgKIN)
         ====       ----        ----         ----
```

BUT...with all this repetition of Cost/Turn/Cust, I was hoping to simplify the queries by adapting the function. After some research, it seems that I should restructure the tables which I really want to avoid. (as this is just a very small part of the puzzle)

I want the users to be able to add other field, so I would also like to avoid complex sql statements.
SO.. I would like to call the function like this

Evaluate Cost: Eval("Cost")

```
Public function Eval(EvalType as variant)
Dim MacD as Variant  (??)
Dim KentF as Variant  (??)
Dim BurgK as Variant  (??)
MacD= EvalType & "MacDON"
KentF= EvalType & "KentFRY"
BurgK= EvalType & "BurgKIN"
```

' this however gives me the names of the 3 fields, and I want to compare the content !?!

```
if MacD>KentF and MacD>KentF
 Eval="MD is the highest"
else
 Eval="MD is NOT the Highest"
endif
```

end function

Does anybody have an idea if this can be done?

Comment: What do you mean by "users to be able to add other field"? Add field where?

Comment: in a standard query design view in access

Comment: You allow users to interact directly with tables and queries?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to open a recordset or use DLookup() aggregate function to pull data from table into function.

Probably also need to pass into function ID of record.

`Public Function Eval(EvalType As Variant, varID As Variant) As String`

Example with DLookup():

`MacD = DLookup(EvalType & "MacDON", "tablename", "ID=" & varID)`

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in your code shows any interaction with tables/recordsets? If you are asking how to retrieve values from fields in a table where the field names are not fixed but can vary dynamically, then that could be done by passing the field name as a variable to eg an open recordset.

Eg you can do

```
MyField$ = "MacDCost" 
MyValue = MyRecordSet(MyField)
```

And you can play with MyField$ to your heart's content. Eg:

```
Dim MyRSt as Recordset
Dim Shops(3) As String
Dim Type(3) As String
Dim ShopTeller as Long
Dim TypeTeller as Long
Dim MyValue as Double

Shops(0)="MacD"
Shops(1)="BurK"
Shops(2)="KenF"
MyType(0)="Cost"
MyType(1)="Turn"
MyType(2)="Cust"

Set MyRst=CurrentDB.OpenRecordset("MyTable")
MyRst.MoveFirst

TypeTeller = 0 
    Do
        MyValue = 0
        ShopTeller = 0
        Do
            myValue = MyValue + CDbl(MyRst(Shops(ShopTeller) & MyType(TypeTeller)))
            ShopTeller = ShopTeller + 1
        Loop Until ShopTeller = UBound(Shops)
        Msgbox "Total " & MyType (TypeTeller) & "from all junk food outlets is :" & MyValue, vbExclamation & VbOKOnly
        TypeTeller = TypeTeller + 1
    Loop Until TypeTeller = UBound(MyType)

MyRst.Close
Set MyRst = Nothing
```

However, if you want the user to be able to add/remove 'shops' etc then you really cannot keep that info in the same table - you will need to, for instance, have a table which contains the Shops and a table which contains the other data (replacing the 2 arrays above) and then link them through an ID field and use JOINs to retrieve the values.